# How to Do localization in Urdu

Tags: android, localization

I have to make an app in Urdu. I want to write Urdu in text view. The Urdu language in this app is going to be every where I mean on buttons , on ActionBar/toolbar. I mean where we see english language in app , it should be converted to Urdu  language.

I have a good idea that this could be done through Localization. But I have soft text in Urdu. I have to use that text and show it How can I save that and use that as a dictionary or encyclopedia.

Please help me How can I change the whole app in Urdu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use localization string file.
Save all string in your values/string.xml(this file contain string for english language) and create localization string file e.g.- values-hi/strings.xml(this contain string for Hindi language).
Use same for Urdu. System automatically choose the string file according to the system selected language.
For more details check out this link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Comment: this is the case. I do not want user to change his system language to hindi . but i want that my app should always appear in hindi, no matter what language in on the system selected by the user

Comment: Than only add hindi translation in values/string.xml. No need to add other string files.

Comment: great I have this idea in my mind. 
so I have to just copy paste the text ?

Comment: Yes you only have to copy and paste translation with respect to there keys.

Answer (score 4):

just change your `values` folder to as `values-ur-rPK`

Comment: why we use rPK here? What is the reason for using "r" with PK?

Answer (score 0):

Try this you don't need to replace string.xml with urudu .

Create separate string resource for urdu and set language during application start up. I think this is the be the best practice

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private Locale locale = null;
    ApplicationComponent mApplicationComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        String lang = "required_lang";
        if (lang != null) {
            changeLang(lang);
        }

    }
public void changeLang(String lang) {
        Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
        if (!"".equals(lang) && !config.locale.getLanguage().equals(lang)) {
            locale = new Locale(lang);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration conf = new Configuration(config);
            conf.locale = locale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(conf, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think under my case I do not need to do localization as I just need hindi (Urdu language) to be show on app , and I think the answer given by Karan Rana is good , what do you think

Comment: Since string.xml is default and is recommenced to store English text . If due to some encoding problem with other language if it fails to find resource it will fetch from the default one . So I just mentioned the recommencement way to do this . To prevent your app from crashing . Now its your call .

Comment: what do you mean . I am copy pasting the urdu text in the strings and it has to show this in urdu . My client just want to see the app in urdu.

Comment: That is what I am saying . Create new locale for urdu . Without editing the default string.xml for urdu language . And on application create set urdu as default language .

Comment: do I need to change  this line .....String lang = "en_US"; with what ?

and also please clear me that the text should be pasted in an separate string file. where I should save it what would be its name ?

Comment: what should I replace in   String lang = "en_US" ?????????? what file name I need to save the new string filw with ?

Comment: Create a string resource for country or language what you need . You will get language code from http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp . Like japanese jp